# (Android)Unable to get the correct screen width for some devices

Tags: android, screen

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    screen_width = display.getWidth();
    screen_height = display.getHeight();
```

I understand that the code above could drive me to get the screen width and height. I put this code in "onCreate" of "MainActivity".

But my friend's mobile device could not show the desired layout. Yet, it is too trouble for me to debug in his mobile device. Thus, I look forward to the help here.

My Question is ...

Is it right to get the width and height in "onCreate"?
Is it useful to get the width and height of all devices? (of course, API>=11)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's right to get the Screen Height and width in onCreate() method because if your Screen rotates then your onCreate will be called. and it's not mandatory that you should take Screen Height & width if needed OK or else you can manage it in Xml as well. To get Screen height and width i think this is the best way...

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
 int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
 int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

for more details you use this link as well
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try metrics instead:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    int displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Doing it in onCreate should be fine.
But honestly, I don't think you are really getting the wrong height and width. The screen size is probably just very different from your test devices.
You will need to debug with his phone at least once to find out what the problem is.
In my opinion it is a good approach to get the width and height, because it gives you more control. Most layout stuff could be done by working with proper layouts (eg LinearLayouts with weight), but there are cases where doing it manually will work better. You can do things more precisely, but it will be more work.
Also if you don't have a large variety of devices for testing it will be tough to adjust it properly. Just think about all the different sizes the Android world can confront you with. I for example had some problems with very small devices, like a Galaxy Mini. Also very big devices like tablets might be a problem. Theres just no way around testing edgecases if you want to do it manually.